# VS 2017 - Reevaluate Data Flow Warnings after correction

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, warnings

**Situation:**
I'm using VS 2017 to build an SSIS package for MS SQL 2017. While building a Data Flow, I add the OLE DB Source and Destination. After mapping the destination, VS correctly identifies a truncation issue and gives me the warning message. (I was trying to put an nvarchar(50) into an nvarchar(10).)

I correct the issue by updating the source to limit the column width to 10 characters. SSIS build and runs fine, but the warning message persists.

**Question:**
Is there some way to force VS to reevaluate the package for warnings/errors? The only way I've found is to delete and re-add the destination, but that is obviously a pain. (Especially when it means remapping columns.)

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not terribly. Slightly less painful might be to select a table above/below the current on in the destination. Click OK and then you get errors everywhere. Go back to the original table and the warnings have gone away.

I suppose closing and re-opening would force the designer to re-evaluate the metadata as well. But no, no button or mouse click to say call the underlying object's `ReinitializeMetaData()` method. At least, I assume that's the call the designer makes and then evaluates conditions like truncation possibilities

Comment: Thank you, swapping the tables out and then back cleared it. I was happy to see it retained the mapping, which was my primary concern.

Answer (score 2):

You can right-click on the Connection Manager for the components that are throwing errors and warnings (this works for errors too), set it to "Work Offline", and then do the same thing - right-click on the Connection Manager to remove the checkmark on "Work Offline". 
When a Connection Manager changes state from "offline" to "online", all of the components and tasks that use it get re-validated.

Comment: This is a great tip, thank you! I accepted billinkc's because I had already used it prior to reading your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I don't remember what version I was working with, but I've seen metadata get "stuck" with the wrong input length, and no amount of reinitializing would clear it. I had to open the Advanced Editor and manually change the length of the input column in order to get the warning to clear.